# Can the same ETH be used to pay for gas for multiple ERC-20 token transfers?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ether, gas, fees

Suppose I deposit two ERC-20 tokens (let's say USDC and USDT) into a single ETH address  with $10 worth of Ether and I now want to transfer both of these tokens to another address. Suppose the current gas costs work out to $10 worth of Ether. Can I use the $10 of ETH to transfer both tokens to an external address or the gas cost would effectively be double - at $10 Ether *per token*? Assuming, I *could* transfer both coins to the same address using a single gas fee, would it be the same if I decided to transfer each token to a different address?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, that's 2 separate transactions, you'll have to pay the gas fee for each one.